# Slicing by same letters

Tags: python, email, slice

I have this email:

```
email= "ABCDEG@University.edu.uk"
```

How I can slice this string to retrieve the sector of this email I mean "edu" by slicing in Python without using negative values in the indexes in slicing?

Comment: probably a regex pattern? or since you know that it is surrounded by "." you can just call split and get the appropriate item from the array

Comment: Sorry, I am failing to understand what you need. What's the criteria of the substring you want to extract?

Comment: `email[18:21]` unless there's more to your problem that you haven't told us.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go and split the email string by "@" which will leave me with the right part of the adress which I would further split by ".".

Code example:

```
firstSplit = email.split("@")
secondSplit = firstSplit[1].split(".")
```

Then, the value you're looking for is *secondSplit[1]*.

If you don't wanna split, you can slice in a way that is specific to this email.

```
mailEduPart = email[18:21]
```

Where 18 is the index of the `e` of edu, and 21 is the `.` after it (exclusive).
On other emails with different lengths, it might not work.

**Edit:** In cases where the email adress has multiple `@` within it, refer to @mozway's comment on this answer.

Comment: there can be several `@` in a valid email address, so better `rsplit` and use negative indexing (which OP doesn't want for unknown reasons)

Comment: @mozway I actually have never seen an email adress with multiple @, good to know. I edited the answer to refer to your comment in such cases.